# upgrade form 2.5 to 3.6

Tags: joomla-2.5, joomla-3.5

After migrating my website from Joomla 2.5 to 3.6, I get the following error when trying to view the homepage:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Joomla\Registry\Registry::loadJSON() in C:\wamp\www\web\templates\hdchannel\html\mod_menu\yjsg_modhelper.php on line 40

what should I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Joomla 3.0, `Registry::loadJSON()` was removed as mentioned [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2), so you need to update this.

Open the following file and go to line 40:

> C:\wamp\www\web\templates\hdchannel\html\mod_menu\yjsg_modhelper.php

Then replace:

```
loadJSON
```

with:

```
loadString
```

Comment: after I do that there is error in the front page :
[500
JHtmlBehavior::mootools not found.
You may not be able to visit this page because of:
an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
a mistyped address
you have no access to this page
The requested resource was not found.
An error has occurred while processing your request.
Please try one of the following pages:
Home Page
Search this site
If difficulties persist, please contact the system administrator of this site.
JHtmlBehavior::mootools not found.]

what the wrong ?

Comment: @SouhailMaatouk - what error is showing now? Also, have you tried installing the Joomla 3.x compatible version of your extension?

Comment: yes its compatible . its template : Hd Channel 
@Lodder

Comment: For the `JHtmlBehavior::mootools not found` error, please see this: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/upgrade-to-j3-gives-jhtmlbehaviormootools-not-found

Comment: If you're still having problems after you've tried the link above, we can carry on chatting here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14071/joomla

Comment: I fix the problems for JHtmlBehavior::mootools : 
after that there is a problem : 
"0

DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (0)"
only in index page 
Do you know what the problem  ?

@Lodder

Comment: I'd suggest asking a new question as your initial one has been answered already.